# Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent and Xamarin.Forms possible conflict

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

I want to try PercentRelativeLayout then i do

New Project -> Android -> Blanck App (Android)

Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent -Version 25.1.1

Install-Package Xamarin.Forms

double click in Main.axml
Clean
Build

And i get this Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Any tip to solve this ? tks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error log, the module of `AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat` is added twice. Please try the following steps to resolve the problem;

1. Remove `Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent` and it's dependency: `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` clean the solution.
2. Add `Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent` with the version of `Xamarin.Forms`'s dependency (ex: If the added `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4`'s version is 23.3.0 then install `Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent` --version 23.3.0).
3. Clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're correct it's a version conflict but Support.Percent version 23.3.0 is too old then i installed in this order: Support.V4 25.1.1 -> Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.224 ( it not replace newer Support.V4) -> Support.Percent  25.1.1 and all is working fine now.